# Restore Java/Selenium webdriver to prior state?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

OK, I have an activity to perform with a Java/Selenium webdriver on a page using frames. I need to specifically set the frames to an element I am dealing with. I would like to be able to restore the webdriver to the state it was in (including its previous frame values) when I return from the method. This is specifically for IE in this case, but the general browser case seems of interest, too.

It seems as though just copying the driver doesn't work. My search found no obvious answers, either here on SO or elsewhere.

Is this a practical goal?

Comment: Can you show us the code and a sample of the HTML?

Comment: Please add the relevant code. Note: copying driver _references_ does not  help, since the "copied" reference points to the same object. Changing reference 2 changes the state of reference 1. You probably want to instruct the driver to switch back to the main document using [`defaultContent()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#defaultContent--). This will reset the diver to the main page [after switching](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#switchTo--) to a frame.

Comment: Unfortunately, the company I'm working for is pretty proprietary, so I can't really provide an example.

As far as switching back to the default content, that's missing the point. I have the system in a given state, looking at a given frame. I'd like to be able to restore it to that exact same state regardless of subsequent actions (other than field value changes... that is, restore the viewing state). There, unfortunately, does not seem to be sufficient information contained in the reference itself.

Comment: I realize, it may not be possible: I guess the closest description is that I'd like to be able to "push the state" of the system (i.e., frame visible, etc.) onto "the stack" for popping it back off later to restore it.
"TIA" for any ideas, thoughts,etc..

Answer (score 0):

It's java so what you can do is make a java program using `Jackson ObjectMapper` you can change `WebDriver` object to a string and copy it to a json file saved it locally, Then you can create a `WebDriver` object again using the json file by `jackson ObjectMapper`

Hope it helps, Just an idea